# Chef::Exceptions::nginx didn't start when installing nginx-1.16.1 from source

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, nginx, chef-infra, cookbook

I am trying to install nginx from source , My requirement is to install specific version of nginx i.e., 1.16.1 because of which i am downloading from source.
After running installNginx.rb , i see nginx.conf file got updated with default nginx configs , but nginx -v says command not found.

below is my configuration -

`installNginx.rb`

```
include_recipe 'nginx::source'

begin
  t = resources(:template => 'nginx.conf')
  t.source 'nginx.conf'
  t.cookbook 'my_nginx'
rescue Chef::Exceptions::ResourceNotFound
  Chef::Log.warn "Could not find template nginx.conf to modify"
end

service 'nginx' do
  action :restart
end
```

`attributes/Source.rb`

```
node.default['nginx']['source']['version'] = '1.16.1'
node.default['nginx']['source']['url'] = 'http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.16.1.tar.gz'
node.default['nginx']['source']['checksum'] = 'f11c2a6dd1d3515736f0324857957db2de98be862461b5a542a3ac6188dbe32b'
```

`metadata.rb`

```
depends 'nginx'
```

After analysing what I observed on cookbook logs is: The source version I gave is `1.16.1` but for some reason, the `nginx::source` recipe is pulling in `1.12.1` and nginx is not starting

```
"nginx": {
"version": "1.12.1",
"package_name": "nginx",
"port": "80",
"dir": "/etc/nginx",
"script_dir": "/usr/sbin",
"log_dir": "/var/log/nginx",
"log_dir_perm": "0750",
"binary": "/opt/nginx-1.12.1/sbin/nginx",
"default_root": "/var/www/nginx-default",
"ulimit": "1024",
"cleanup_runit": true,
"repo_source": "nginx",
"install_method": "package",
"user": "webadmin",
"upstart": {
"runlevels": "2345",
"respawn_limit": null,
"foreground": true
}


"init_style": "init",
"source": {
"version": "1.16.1",
"prefix": "/opt/nginx-1.12.1",
"conf_path": "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf",
"sbin_path": "/opt/nginx-1.12.1/sbin/nginx",
"default_configure_flags": [
"--prefix=/opt/nginx-1.12.1",
"--conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf",
"--sbin-path=/opt/nginx-1.12.1/sbin/nginx",
"--with-cc-opt=-Wno-error"
],
"url": "http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.16.1.tar.gz",
"checksum": "f11c2a6dd1d3515736f0324857957db2de98be862461b5a542a3ac6188dbe32b",
"modules": [
"nginx::http_ssl_module",
"nginx::http_gzip_static_module"
],


INFO: remote_file[nginx source] created file /var/chef/runs/58bffee4-b5aa-4632-97cd-0eeacc4ebd4c/local-mode-cache/cache/nginx-1.16.1.tar.gz
INFO: remote_file[nginx source] updated file contents /var/chef/runs/58bffee4-b5aa-4632-97cd-0eeacc4ebd4c/local-mode-cache/cache/nginx-1.16.1.tar.gz
```

I am unable to figure out where the issue is, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The attributes file in the nginx cookbook refers to the default version in multiple  places. For example, it uses the default version to define the directory where nginx is installed to as well as download URL for the nginx sources as

```
default['nginx']['source']['prefix'] = "/opt/nginx-#{node['nginx']['source']['version']}"
default['nginx']['source']['url'] = "http://nginx.org/download/nginx-#{node['nginx']['source']['version']}.tar.gz"
```

Thus, if you later update the `version` attribute in your own cookbook, the download URL will not automatically be updated with the new version since it has no reference to it anymore.

To resolve this, you have two options

1. You can manually set **all** related attributes in your cookbook. This is likely error-prone and may lead to inconsistencies as you have seen.
2. You can reload the default nginx attributes file after having set the overridden attributes. This can look like this in your attributes file:

   ```
   override['nginx']['version'] = '1.16.1'
   override['nginx']['source']['checksum'] = 'f11c2a6dd1d3515736f0324857957db2de98be862461b5a542a3ac6188dbe32b'

   # Reload nginx::source attributes with our updated version
   node.from_file(run_context.resolve_attribute('nginx', 'source'))
   ```

Note that the nginx cookbook maintains two nginx versions: `node['nginx']['version']` and `node['nginx']['source']['version']`, with the latter value being set to the former value by default.

In your ohai output, you have only seen the `node['nginx']['version']` attribute (which you have not overridden).

By overriding this attribute and reloading the `attributes/source.rb` file as shown about, things should be consistent again.